# JAVASCRIPT + HTML Button Value with getElements

Tags: javascript

I don't want to pass the value to the function, I want it to find the value itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(buttonNum)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    alert(document.myform.elements[buttonNum].value);
}
</script>


<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="q" onclick="add(0)"/>
<input type="button" value="w" onclick="add(1)"/>
<input type="button" value="e" onclick="add(2)"/>
<input type="button" value="r" onclick="add(3)"/>
<input type="button" value="t" onclick="add(4)"/>
<input type="button" value="y" onclick="add(5)"/>
</form>
```

If I wanted to click on a button and display the value of the button into lets say a div; I don't want to code every button with an onclick(passing a parameter).

What approaches do I need to take? Something tells me that I need to get the length, run a for loop, and attach a handler. I'm just not sure on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply pass `this` as parameter so that you can access all the attributes of the element but here only value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(elem)
{

    alert(elem.value);
}
</script>


<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="q" onclick="add(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="w" onclick="add(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="e" onclick="add(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="r" onclick="add(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="t" onclick="add(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="y" onclick="add(this)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I modified it even more.

<script type="text/javascript">
function add(element)
{
    alert(element.innerHTML);
}
</script>

<div id="q"><button onclick="add(this)">q</button></div>

Either way, both methods work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

```
getElementsByTagName("button");

<input>
```

You are getting the wrong element type.

---

> If I wanted to click on a button and display the value of the button into lets say a div; I don't want to code every button with an onclick(passing a parameter).

Use `addEventListener`. You can identify the element clicked with `event.target`

e.g.

```
addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.type == "button") {
        alert(evt.target.value);
    }
});
```